# Cannot switch between 2 operating systems

Tags: windows, debian, multi-boot

Guyz...
   I've installed two OS i.e. Win 8 and a Debian distro. First I installed the debian one and then partitioned some free space for WIN 8 and then installed Win 8. The problem here arises that whenever I start my laptop, it directly loads Windows 8 and I'm not able to select the Debian one. How do I do it ?
   I've even checked in the MSCONFIG file, it shows only WIN 8 but no other OS but I'm sure I've another OS installed and I didn't mess anything up. Everything was done carefully. So, please help me over here.. :-/

Comment: You need to install a boot-loader - you can use a arch-linux CD to achieve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The golden rule of dual booting is **ALWAYS** install Windows first. In your case, it would just be easiest to format your HDD (using gparted on a liveCD, for example) and re-install everything again.

Make sure Windows 8 goes on first. Once it does, Debian should sort everything else out for you (GRUB, whatnot and etc.)

Comment: you mean to say I should RE-FORMAT everything again ! Can I just not format Debian distro and re-install it ? Logically, that would make Win 8 as 1st installed and the other one as 2nd installed... Is there any other possibility than formatting Win 8 bcoz I dont mind formatting the other one.

Also, I read somewhere that things can work without formatting also but it is a long procedure. I googled a lot but I couldn't find that particular PROCEDURE :)

Comment: @DeAtHvAdEr the first thing to try would be to reinstall debian over itself, you've already got everything in place so all it needs is for debian to install its bootloader. During installation make sure that when it mentions the boot loader that your current Windows 8 install is detected.

Comment: guyz...thanx for the info
would do it when I get bored of the particular OS and decide to change it. And the problem was solved by EasyBCD software...Works like a charm

Comment: -1 DO NOT REFORMAT! Why in the world would you need to? All you have to do is boot into a live linux cd, `chroot` and install a bootloader.